# How to repeat the values until next non-empty row and then repeat next row's data and so on with Google Apps Script?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The challenge here is to capture the customer ID and its name and repeat it down below until the script reaches the next non-empty row. Then, the next ID and customer name are the ones that will be repeated.

This is just how far I've gotten on my own, but I can't build the core of the logic mylself (yes).

```
function repeatValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const originData = sheet.getRange(6, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  for (var a = 0; a < originData.length; a++) {
      if (originData[a][0] != ''){
        var customerID = originData[a][0];
        var customer = originData[a][1];
      }
      if (originData == ''){
        targetSheet.getRange(2,1,originData.length, originData.length).setValue(customerID);
      }        
      }
  }
```

Here's a link to the sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wU3dql6dnh_JBC6yMkrFzEYxdyzyNdkBmve2pfyxG0g/edit?usp=sharing

Expected Result includes these values in blue repeated:
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question and your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike! The savior! I've included the expected result above.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the following situation. (The following image is from your question.) You want to add the texts of blue font color.

  [image]
- You want to put the values to "Sheet2".

#### Modification points:

- In your script, at `const originData = sheet.getRange(6, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();`, the start row is `6`. In this case, please modify `sheet.getLastRow()` to `sheet.getLastRow() - 5`
- In order to create an array for putting to "Sheet2", it is required to check the columns "A" and "B" of "Sheet1". For this, in this modification, I used `temp` as follows.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function repeatValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const originData = sheet.getRange(6, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 5, 3).getValues(); // Modified
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  
  // I added below script.
  let temp = ["", ""];
  const putValues = originData.map(([a, b, c]) => {
    if (a.toString() && b.toString() && temp[0] != a && temp[1] != b) {
      temp = [a, b];
    }
    return temp.concat(c);
  });
  targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, putValues.length, putValues[0].length).setValues(putValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script is for your sample Spreadsheet. So when the structure of Spreadsheet is changed, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. 
I've read your profile on the internet and I think that you have contributed to thousandds of people with your work. Thanks a million for the part that has helped me so far! All the best! You got one more fan from Brazil!

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying and testing it. And, I'm honored for it. Also, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.